# How to implement caching in ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, caching, video, exoplayer

How can I implement caching in ExoPlayer? It is really bad that it always re-downloads the entire video...

I tried the following approach in my RendererBuilder:

```
Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter(player.getMainHandler(),
    null);

SimpleCache cache = (SimpleCache) Singleton.getSingleton(context).getCache();

// Always prints 0, that's the problem!
Log.d("CacheSize", String.valueOf(cache.getCacheSpace()));

DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, bandwidthMeter, userAgent);

CacheDataSource cacheDataSource = new CacheDataSource(cache, dataSource, false, false);


ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(uri, cacheDataSource, allocator,
    BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
```

And inside my Singleton's constructor:

```
this.cache = new SimpleCache(context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(1024 * 1024 * 8));
```

But it seems that it's not working, as the video takes a while to load, and the printed cache space is always 0! Tried to do some searches on the subject, but every question about it is not answered, never saw a working example.